# How can I sleep at night with all the suffering in the world?

Tags: ethics

In most cases, it's considered to be immoral, distasteful or heartless to just cheerily continue what you're doing upon hearing of a tragedy or cruelty without at least pausing to reflect on it, even if you don't know the people involved (e.g. hearing in the news or word-of-mouth).

Quite often, people will get upset about such bad news, or even the knowledge that such things do happen.

(e.g. upon seeing a disturbing scene in a fictional TV programme, my wife became upset by it. When I said that it was "just a TV show", she rightly pointed out that while this instance is fictional, these kinds of things do happen in real life).

Continuing from that, every single day, people are murdered, raped, tortured, bullied, subjected to cruelty, children are neglected, forced into slavery, people are starving, and so on. These instances are no less unjust or tragic whether I've heard of the specific instances or not, or whether they happen next door or the other side of the world. I know it's happening even if I don't know of any specific cases. Surely I should be as outraged by them as I would be if I found out my next door neighbour routinely left their children alone and hungry while they spent all their money at the pub.

But on the other hand, if we were all to get upset about every single tragedy that is occurring in the world, we'd all simply have to lead a dismal existence for our entire lives.

Is there a philosophy or argument that excuses us from ignoring the thousands of tragedies that happen every day so we can get on with our lives?

(I don't think the argument that "there's nothing we can do about the vast majority of it, so why worry about it?" quite fits. We will often still get angry or sad about specific bad news we hear whether we can do anything about it or not)

Comment: Well Kantian ethics is generally taken to hold that 'ought implies can'. If you agree with this view, and agree with the claim that it is not psychologically healthy (or indeed possible) to become upset and angry about every bad thing that happens in the world, then you have your argument. As a separate argument, I don't think it is by any means clear that we are obliged to be equally morally concerned with events that in no way involve us, there are plenty of ways of thinking about ethics which would not support this view.

Comment: Suffering is a natural mechanism, and it is not bad per se. The consequences of suffering are usually constructive (physically: the body becomes resilient; emotionally: the spirit grows). It is not nice to suffer, of course, but suffering makes learning. Even more, there are people who choose suffering in order to grow spiritually (e.g. monks, religious, Bukowski-es, Gandhi-es, etc.). I would say that nature has a limited control over our suffering limits, and perhaps suffering is excessive. But such excess leads to equilibrium.

Comment: just don't fall asleep? rage against the dying of the light.

Comment: Another alternative is to turn against nature, cause she's cruel (anti-naturalism). Or against men (misanthropy). Or against God (anti-theism). See also https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffering-focused_ethics

Comment: This sounds like a version of ["children are starving in Africa"](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AppealToWorseProblems) guilt trip that has the fallacy of relative privation at its core. Our emotional responses are preludes to action, and they evolved when we had no access to information about distant events that we cannot in any way affect. So moral intuitions about their appropriateness in a small social circle do not apply beyond it. We do have capacity to affect distant events *sometimes*, but otherwise emotions are blank rounds that only distract and exhaust us needlessly.